# Get regex to match a group any amount of times

Tags: python, regex

Given the string:

`Created by [[User:One|One]] ([[User talk:One|talk]]), [[User:Two|Two]] ([[User talk:Two|talk]]).&nbsp;Nominated by [[User:Three|Three]] ([[User talk:Three|talk]]) at 23:47, 25 January 2014 (UTC)`

How could I get a regex like `(\[\[User:(.*?)\|.*?\]\]\s?)` (which would match `[[User:One|One]]`) to match it recursively until it reaches the `.&nbsp;`?

Thank you in advance. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ´findall´ that give you a list with all the matches in the string:

```
import re

str = "Created by [[User:One|One]] ([[User talk:One|talk]]), [[User:Two|Two]] ([[User talk:Two|talk]]).&nbsp;Nominated by [[User:Three|Three]] ([[User talk:Three|talk]]) at 23:47, 25 January 2014 (UTC), How could I get a regex like (\[\[User:(.*?)\|.*?\]\]\s?)"

matcher = re.compile("(\[\[User:(.*?)\|.*?\]\]\s?)")
print matcher.findall(str)
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

If you want to finish always at the `".&nbsp"` you can split the string and take only the first element as:

```
untilnbsp = str.split(".&nbsp")[0]
```

That will give you just the string `"Created by [[User:One|One]] ([[User talk:One|talk]]), [[User:Two|Two]] ([[User talk:Two|talk]])"`, and now you can use the `findall` with it